# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting Dates

Tags: date, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

New to Conditional Formatting. Looking to take a column of Dates (these dates are project end dates) compare them to Today's date and format them to change color whether they are 60 days prior to end date, 30 days prior to equal to end date (day of), and past end date.

Comment: Sorry let me clarify. Col A would have Project End Dates. Ex: 12/31/2014. Based on my current date: A: if I was 60 days out, my cell would be green. If I was between 60 and 30 days out, it would be orange, if my current date was equal to project end date cell would be red, and if my current date was past project end date, it would be dark red... Somethign like this.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure this is exactly what you want (eg no formatting today>today+30, 60 days *or more*) but perhaps four rules, say all applied to Range A:A,  where *Custom formula is*:

Red: `=A1=today()`
Dark red: `=and(A1<today(),A1<>"")`
Orange: `=and(A1>today()+30,A1<today()+60)`
Green: `=A1>today()+30`

Note that the order may make a difference.

Comment: pnuts, how you adding these in? custom?